# Does Ubuntu format my hardrive

Tags: system-installation, format

I have been reading and I want to install Ubuntu. I saw it says that it can use all the hard drive and override the other OS. So my question is, will it delete everything in my hard drive and install itself or will it delete my OS only?

Comment: If you choose "Install alongside" option, Ubuntu installation will resize your disk into two parts, one for Ubuntu and the other for your other OS

Comment: And if you choose "Replace Windows", it will delete _everything_, including your OS and data.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if -you- tell the installer to overwrite an OS it will format anything related to that OS. So, assuming Windows, C:, D:, E: and any other drive letters.

If the other OS is Ubuntu it will delete all partitions related to the OS.

If you have create "unallocated space" from the OS you use now you can use that to "install alongside" and you will have the new OS together with another OS. That will not delete your old OS.

---

As with any action that involves changing the disk layout: make a backup of your important files on any of the operating systems. It is even better to have a regular backup schedule.

Comment: ...and whatever you do, make a backup of your important data. Even if you decide not to install anything.

Comment: @rmano so true :-)

Comment: thanks for the info but i have a file stored directly to my hard drive will that be deleted is my question it isn't in the desktop or documents its in my c drive

Comment: The answer is pretty clear: --if-- you tell the system to overwrite Windows it will remove anything related to Windows. That includes that file on the C: drive. Again: make a backup.